# how to add plot bar on Angular nvD3 Chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I need to add a simple line bar on angular nvD3 chart to display an event on time serie. like on this screenshot: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X95T2.jpg

Does anyone know how to do that or to add plot bands?

Thank you for help